# JavaScript no meio do código?

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber em que situações práticas um script JS seria escrito no meio do código HTML e não declarado num arquivo à parte no ***head*** ou no fim do ***body***.

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Às vezes eu uso apenas por questões de praticidade, para facilitar a manutenção. Se é bom ou ruim, nunca procurei saber. Em outros casos quando envolve back-end, onde eu quero executar um script numa determinada posição dependendo de uma variável back-end, o que eu não conseguiria fazer em um .js a parte.

Answer (score 0):

eu conheço por exemplo o EJS, é um engine do JavaScript e serve para quando você quer trazer dados do back end para o front end, e exibir em um campo, label, entre outros. Isso você consegue fazer no meio do HTML.